# what is a good way to convert a vector mock up into html?

Tags: inkscape

I'm am trying to make a three column layout for a website from an inkscape mockup that I made. The problem is that I am more of an artist that a programer, so I know only the basics. I will take any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on the topic. The float property is important to get a three column layout to work.

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/threecolumnlayout.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your budget you could try http://www.psd2html.com/ or there are plenty of other options online.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably automated solutions, but I've never found an automated tool that writes good, clean code.

With just a little bit of HTML and CSS knowledge, you can make some great layouts using the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs).  I've been using it for the last several projects I've worked on, and found it to be flexible enough for most needs.

Answer (score 0):

Some mockup tools (like Axura and ForeUI) can do this job, but you have to create the mockup with these tools before.